# Are calico and ingress controller pods necessary to run on each worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have AKS cluster with one system nodepool with one node. I am able to deploy ingress controller on it and all calico pods are running first but if I add user nodepool with one node. I see one more calico pods that is running but is not in ready state. Why? And if I deploy ingress controller again its pods crashes. Why?

Comment: could you please share any logs or events which could help to answer.